# Do I need to do anything after upgrading my ram from 2gb tp 4gb(2x2gb)

Tags: ram, pae

I got a new 2GB RAM stick and I am going to add it alongside my existing 2GB card making it 2x2GB=4GB RAM.

Do I have to do anything extra to make it work as 4GB fully?

Anything to do with the PAE kernel stuff?? (I already have a PAE kernel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the 64-bit or PAE kernel; Nope.

Either of these kernels will detect and automatically use all 4GB of memory. The pae kernel is the default for Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have to do anything, unless you want to upgrade from a 32bit to 64 bit system and you want to use a 64bit OS.

The only thing that you **might** have to do is adjust your swap file size.  to do that take a look at [Swap FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq/)

Answer (score 3):

If 4GB RAM is detected via `free -m` or through **`System monitor`** and since you already have PAE Kernel installed , then you have to do **Nothing** .